# Elements placed randomly in panel

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm looking for panel, which can place every item in collection in random place, with random rotation.
It will be great, if it would be open source!

I'm writing in WinRT, XAML, but I can port it from SL/WPF.

Does anyone knows something like that?

Comment: I don't know of one, but randomising the position of items on a canvas doesn't sound like a difficult job.  Why not roll your own?

Comment: Lazyness :) So, I will wait few hours and if noone knows, case closed :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a regular `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, and bind the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` to a random value generated somewhere

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" 
                    Value="{Binding SomeRandomValue}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" 
                    Value="{Binding SomeRandomValue}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

How you get the Random value is up to you. You can set it as a property on your data item, return a random value from a `Converter`, create a static resource that gives you a random value, etc

Comment: I made something similar by my own. Thank you!